# Is it possible to create only ssh password for user without any password?

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, redhat-enterprise-linux

Using `PermitEmptyPasswords yes` is totally insecure.

Is it possible to create password only for ssh connection, but not for local user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure it is, 
I assume you already have the no-password local user created?

```
ssh-keygen
```

will prompt you for a 'ssh password' when creating your new keys, you can then copy them to remote server using

```
ssh-copy-id
```

__if your user already has keys created, you can use

```
ssh-keygen -p -f <user_home_dir>/.ssh/id_rsa
```

-p will update the password of the existing keyfile. Hope it helps